# How to design this cover page

Tags: titles

I came across this image:

[image]

I was wondering how to manage the vertical book title in pdflatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You can do it with standard elements as described in Lamport's book on LaTeX or any other tutorial on LaTeX, most notably using the commands `\scalebox`, `\rotatebox`, `\sffamily`, `\bfseries`, `\Huge` and the environments `minipage` and `titlepage`. For the width of the `minipage`, you can either find it by trial and error, or you use `\newlength` and `\settowidth`. If you get stuck with a concrete problem or you have questions regarding how to get rid of the borders, how to change background and foreground colour, etc come back to TeX.SX.

Answer (score 10):

With [`bookcover`](http://ctan.org/pkgs/bookcover) class, you can completely design the cover with all its components: front, back, spine and flaps.

An example:

```
\documentclass[marklength=0mm,
    bleedwidth=0mm,
    spinewidth=20mm]{bookcover}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\setbookcover{bgcolor}{whole}{%
color=gray!80!brown!30,
}

%back cover
\setbookcover{fgfirst}{back}{%
\vfill
\hfill
\resizebox{100mm}{!}{%
    \rotatebox{-90}{\textsf{\textbf{\color{white}{\parbox{10cm}{\raggedright STOP SAYING\\ I WILL\\ START DOING}}}}}}
%\vfill
}

%front cover
\setbookcover{fgfirst}{front}{%
%\vfill
\resizebox{100mm}{!}{%
    \rotatebox{-90}{\textsf{\textbf{\color{white}{\parbox{10cm}{\raggedright STOP SAYING\\ I WILL\\ START DOING}}}}}}
%\vfill
}

%spine
\setbookcover{fgfirst}{spine}{
\vfill
\centering
\resizebox{10mm}{!}{
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\textsf{\textbf{\color{white}Stop saying I will start doing}}}}
\vfill}

\makebookcover
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, b5paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,  x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin = 0pt,  noheadfoot}
\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}\newpagecolor{Khaki4}
\rotatebox[origin=lt]{-90}{
\adjustbox{width=\paperheight}{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\color{LightGoldenrod1}%
\begin{tabular}{l}%
STOP SAYING \\[-0.7ex]
I WILL \\[-0.7ex]
START DOING\\[-0.5ex]\end{tabular}}}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but \usepackage{classico} gives an error in LaTeX. Do I have to download it manually?

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: 2016/bin/x86_64-darwin and I'm using TexPad for Mac

Comment: I've just discovered it's not part of the TeX Live distribution.  You can download the package ready-to-install (`classico.tds.zip`) from [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/classico) on CTAN. Just unzip the file at the root of your `texmf-local` directory. As I'm on MiKTeX, I'm n)ot sure whether you have to write something in a local `updmap.cfg` and run `updmap -sys` on MacTeX to update the type1 fonts database, but someone here will tell you for sure.